# Use Magnetometer and Accelerometer to calculate accurate Yaw

Tags: ios, swift, accelerometer, core-motion, magnetometer

I'm currently using CMMotionManager attitude to get roll, pitch and yaw. However, after running for a few minutes, yaw is drifting and becoming not accurate.

I read there is a way to calculate the yaw using a combination of accelerometer and magnetometer that will keep yaw accurate with a compensation for the constant drift, however, I haven't yet found a working formula.

Here is a little part of my code that I use for getting motion updates.

```
motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.1
motionManager.showsDeviceMovementDisplay = true
motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates(using: .xMagneticNorthZVertical, to: OperationQueue.current!)
    { deviceManager, error in

    if let deviceManager = deviceManager {
        let roll = deviceManager?.attitude.roll
        let pitch deviceManager?.attitude.pitch
        let yaw = deviceManager?.attitude.yaw // Get drifted over time
...
```

Any idea?

**UPDATE**

I could compensate the yaw drift by using the following formula:

Create initial reference point (fixed world frame reference) using magnetometer:

```
m_w = (m_x,m_y,m_z)
```

Take current magnetomer point (also fixed world frame reference) using magnetometer:

```
n_w = (n_x,n_y,n_z)
```

Convert projected reading to angles

```
a = atan2(m_z,m_x)
b = atan2(n_z,n_x)
```

Yaw drift can be calculated as follows

```
y_d = (a-b) * 180 / PI
```

Now deduct result from current accelerometer yaw.

WALLA!

Answer (score 0):

Don't you mean giro? The MotionManager has a mode in where it mixes 3 inputs, Accelerometer, Gyroscope and the Magnetometer.

For this you gotta set it up to "Device motion"

> Device motion. Call the  startDeviceMotionUpdates(using:)  or 
>   startDeviceMotionUpdates()  method to begin updates and periodically
>   access  CMDeviceMotion  objects by reading the  deviceMotion 
>   property. The startDeviceMotionUpdates(using:) method (new in iOS 5.0)
>   lets you specify a reference frame to be used for the attitude
>   estimates.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmmotionmanager

However, you must be aware that this increases the battery consumption quite a bit.

Comment: This is what I do at the moment as I stated, I do use a CMMotionManager to get updates of roll, pitch, and yaw. However, yaw get drifted after a while, and i understand this is a common issue with gyros. I am looking for a solution.